# HttpURLConnection times out on certain devices -- very mysterious behavior

Tags: java, android, timeout, httpurlconnection, android-networking

I have an app that relies on making POST/GET requests. My app is being tested by a variety of devices on the same wifi network.

On some devices I get the standard timeout exception for HttpURLConnection.

Below is where the timeout occurs:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(
                    getString(R.string.base_url) + "/getnumbers").openConnection()));
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(MainActivity.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS);
            conn.setReadTimeout(MainActivity.READ_TIMEOUT_MS);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", prefs.getString("sessionid", ""));
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.connect();


            JSONObject progress = new JSONObject();
            try {
                progress.put("username", prefs.getString("username", ""));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  

            // posting it
            Writer wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(progress.toString());
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            is = conn.getResponseCode() >= 400 ? conn.getErrorStream() :
                    conn.getInputStream();
```

**This app works fine with the following devices:**

- Samsung Galaxy S4    Verizon 5.0.1
- Samsung Galaxy S5    Verizon 6.0.1
- Samsung Galaxy S7    AT&T    6.0.1
- Samsung Galaxy S7    Verizon 6.0.1
- Samsung  Galaxy S7 Edge  Verizon 6.0.1
- BLU R1 HD    N/A 6.0.1
- Galaxy Tab S2
- LG G4    Verizon 6.0.1
- LG G2 Verizon  5.1.1
- Google Pixel At&t 7.1.1
- Sony Xperia Z Ultra  Verizon  5.1.1

**Here is the list of devices that cause the timeout issue:**

- LG Tribute HD    No Plan 6.0.1
- LG V10   Verizon 6.0.1
- LG Zone 3        5.1.1
- Samsung Note 4   ATT&T   6.0.1

I tried fixing the timeout issue by extending the timeout duration and by doing System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false"). None of these measures helped.

Considering that the timeout occurs on the same Wifi network, I am fairly certain that the issue is caused by the vendor specific bloatware or some other device/vendor/operator specific problem.

Can anyone share their ideas thoughts as to what might be causing this?

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
```

W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
 W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)

Comment: What 'standard timeout exception'? Connect timeout? Connection timeout? Read timeout? Stack trace please.

Comment: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
 W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
 W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so releasing the app through Play Store seemed to solve the problem with (at least) one of the devices (the Note 4 which had updated to 6.0.2 recently).

So some of the devices seem to timeout when APKs are installed directly but work when installed via Play Store.